# Inserting int into sorted multidimensional list

Tags: python-3.x

I need to insert an int into a sorted list.

Here's what I got so far:

```
def insert_in_list(x, tree, index=0):
    if not tree:
        return tree
    elif x < tree[index]:
        tree.insert(index, x)
        return tree
    else:
        return insert_in_list(x, tree, index+1)
```

This is working on all one-dimensional lists for example, [1,5,10]. However, I need it to work on any list containing additional lists, for example: [1,[5,7[8,9,10]]18,22].

Tried this:

```
def insert_in_list(x, tree, index=0):
    if not tree:
        return x
    elif isinstance(tree[0], list):
        return [insert_in_list(x, tree[0])] + insert_in_list(x, tree[1:])
    elif x < tree[index]:
        tree.insert(index, x)
        return tree
    else:
        return insert_in_list(x, tree, index+1)
```

However, insert_in_list(4, [[2,3,6], 8, 10])) returns [[[[2, 3, 4, 6]]], 4, 8, 10]. So the recursion doesn't stop after inserting the first 4. help me out

Comment: how do you sort list of lists?  where to insert the value `4` in  `[0, 1, 3, [2, 7, 8], 6, 11 ]` ? can't you flaten you lists?

Comment: Well it's for an assignment in school. All lists provided are already sorted, ascending from left to right. So your example is irrelevant. But I have to return the list "unflattened"!

Comment: If answered your question, then please check it as valid, else tell me what the problem is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happen because you need to tell your function to stop looking for x < item when the upper bound is found.
This is an additional signal (variable `done`) that propagates as soon as an upper bound is found.

```
def insert_in_list(x, tree, done = False):
    for index, item in enumerate(tree):
        if isinstance(item, list):
            done = insert_in_list(x, item)
        elif done:
            return True
        elif x < item:
            tree.insert(index, x)
            return True
```

Additionnaly

- you don't need the index as parameter since you'll insert inside the loop, other instances of your function don't need to know that last index.
- list are mutable, so it is allways the same list even if you don't pass it as parameter.